# Declaring constant absolute 64-bit addresses in NASM

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, x86-64, nasm

I need to declare a dummy absolute address in the code of a self-modifying program. This pointer works similar to a relocation for a linker - it only reserves appropriate space in the instruction and is updated with a valid address later on at runtime. This has worked fine for me on x86-32:

```
movups xmm0, [0xDEADBEEF]
```

This assembles and works as expected at runtime. However, when I try to do this in x86-64 code:

```
movups xmm0, [0xDEADC0DEDEADBEEF]
```

It assembles with the following warning:

```
warning: dword data exceeds bounds
```

And promptly crashes at runtime because the next instruction is overwritten with the rest of the address, which happens to be garbage instruction-wise.

Any address longer than 32 bits fails to assemble without a warning, even a minimally longer one than 32 bits:

```
movups xmm0, [0xADEADBEEF] ; 36-bit address
```

How should I go about declaring a constant, absolute 64-bit pointer? Or is there just no way around it and I need to drop a RIP-relative, 32-bit pointer in there?

Comment: Could it be related to the fact that x86 hardware and operating systems don't (yet) use all 64 bits of the address bus? [How much memory can a 64bit machine address at a time](http://superuser.com/questions/168114/how-much-memory-can-a-64bit-machine-address-at-a-time)

Comment: I cannot see why you even assume I'm running this code under any OS. :) No, these are raw assembly instructions, this is not related to an OS's ability to address memory at all.

Comment: I'm assuming that the assembler might know that no hardware can use all 64 address bits on an x86.

Comment: ...which would be quite short-sighted, as such hardware may arrive in the near future and the assembler would become unnecessarily impaired. No, I think I'm either missing a concept here (more probable) or it's simply a bug in NASM.

Comment: I find it really odd that it assembles with just a warning. That memory address is completely unencodable for that instruction (and the vast majority of other instructions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be wrong because I haven't done NASM in a long time, but I don't think you can use a 64 bit immediate value with any register other than `AL, AX, EAX, RAX`.  Your 64 bit address has to be declared as a `QWORD`.

Solution:

```
mov rax , 0xDEADCODEDEADBEEF
movups xmm0, [rax]
```

See comments below for explanation.

This reference: [NASM Manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdo11.html)

Comment: It's not that simple. I tried "routing" the pointer via RAX: `lea rax, [0xDEADCODEDEADBEEF] \n movups xmm0, [rax]` And the warning doesn't change, only it now complains about the `lea` instruction instead of `movups`. I've read through the manual several times already and can't find anything useful.

Comment: Also, declaring the address as `[qword 0xDEADCODEDEADBEEF]` only leads to an additional warning: `warning: displacement size ignored on absolute address`, with the previous one *not* going away.

Comment: @IneQuation did you try `[abs qword 0xDEADCODEDEADBEEF]` ?

Comment: @IneQuation or declare the constant in your data section `x dd 0xDEADCODEDEADBEEF` then use `movups xmm0, [x]`

Comment: Thanks, Trevor, I'll try inlining the data in the code and see how it works out. :)

Comment: On second thoughts, this is not a viable solution for me as it requires an additional dereference. The piece of code I'm putting together is size- and performance-critical and I can afford neither the code bloat nor the dereference overhead (which is why I went for self-modifying code in the first place).

Comment: @IneQuation This may be pointless to try.

`mov rax , 0xDEADCODEDEADBEEF` then `movups xmm0, [rax]`

I'm sure you've tried that.  Sorry I couldn't be much help :(

Comment: This answer is right, but not very descriptive. You can only use a 64-bit absolute address for *moving* to/from the accumulator, not for any operation with it. You can, however, move a 64-bit immediate value into any 64-bit GPR, which is what you are trying to do. `mov rax, 0xDEADCODEDEADBEEF \n movups xmm0, [rax]` (Edit: Just noticed Trevor posted that code while I was looking for the reference to make sure there were no other operations that could use it.)

Comment: @TrevorArjeski: Indeed I have, but I must've did something wrong because I'm sure it didn't work before... It does now, for whatever reason.